# Prove that if $(a_n)$ is a monotone increasing sequence of integers then $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac{1}{a_n})^{a_n}=e$

Tags: limits, monotone-functions

I'm asked to prove the question above.

I need to show that if $(a_n)$ is an increasing sequence of **integers** then:
$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{a_n}\right)^{a_n}=e$

I was thinking of showing that $\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_n)=\infty$
and then, by definition, I can say that there exists a natural number $N$, such that for every $n>N, a_n>0$ and so $(a_n)^\infty_{n=N}$ is a sub-sequence of $(1+\frac{1}{n})^n$ and therefore shares the same limit- $e$

Any ideas?

Comment: If you take $a_n = \omega(n)$ this statement is not true

Comment: sorry, I don't quite get it: what is it you want to show? then the limit equals to what?

Comment: Did you mean to write: $\lim_{n\to\infty} \left( 1 + \frac{1}{a_n}\right)^{a_n} = e$?

Comment: If so, then I think your proof would work. There are a few way to show $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = \infty$. I think arguing that $a_n \geq a_0 + n$ makes sense.

Comment: Is your sequence known to be unbounded?

Comment: I'm terribly sorry, I wasn't being clear. I've edited the question so I think it's easier to follow what I'm asking now... Thanks for your patience.

Comment: I don't know how to remove the on hold so I clarified the question here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1752303/a-n-is-a-monotone-increasing-sequence-of-integers-prove-that-lim-n-to-i