# $(a_n)$ is a monotone increasing sequence of integers. Prove that: $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac{1}{a_n})^{a_n}=e$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I'm asked to prove the question above.

I need to show that if $(a_n)$ is an increasing sequence of **integers** then:
$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{a_n}\right)^{a_n}=e$

I was thinking of showing that $\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_n)=\infty$
and then, by definition, I can say that there exists a natural number $N$, such that for every $n>N, a_n>0$ and so $(a_n)^\infty_{n=N}$ is a sub-sequence of $(1+\frac{1}{n})^n$ and therefore shares the same limit- $e$

Any ideas?

Comment: $(a_n)$ is anyway a subsequence of the increasing sequence of integers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prove that if $(a_n)$ is a monotone increasing sequence of integers then $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+\frac{1}{a_n})^{a_n}=e$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1749728/prove-that-if-a-n-is-a-monotone-increasing-sequence-of-integers-then-lim)

Comment: @lastresort Indeed this is a duplicate but in the link there is no answer and that question is on hold, which is as good as the question not existing.

Comment: @Joanpemo Noted, will take more care next time.

Comment: @Nofar Duani - You can also use the following result ,  $1+x \leq e^x$

Comment: $x \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: your argument is correct and fully rigorous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your reasoning is correct. As there exists some $N$ for which $a_n>0$ for all $n\geq N$, it follows that $a_{N+k} \geq k$ (as $(a_n)$ is an increasing integer sequence).

Hence,
$$ \left(1+\frac{1}{n-N}\right)^{n-N} \leq \left(1+\frac{1}{a_n}\right)^{a_n} \leq e, \quad\text{for $n > N$} $$

the left hand side approaches e, so the limit of the sequence converges by the squeeze theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Since $\;a_n\nearrow\infty$ , we get that $\;\left\{a_n\right\}\subset\Bbb N\;$ is a subsequence of $\;\{n\}_{n=1}^\infty=\Bbb N\;$ , and since the limit of any subsequence of a converging sequence exists and equals the limit of the sequence, we get what we want.