# Calculate and prove the limit $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty }(1+\frac{1}{a_n})^{a_n}$ Given $a_n$ is an increasing monotone sequence of integers

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, solution-verification, eulers-number-e

> $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty }(1+\frac{1}{a_n})^{a_n}$ given $(a_n)$ is an increasing sequence of integers

NOTE - I noticed these 2 questions [here (1)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1752303/a-n-is-a-monotone-increasing-sequence-of-integers-prove-that-lim-n-to-i) and [here (2)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1749728/prove-that-if-a-n-is-a-monotone-increasing-sequence-of-integers-then-lim) but I believe that my question is a bit different because these questions answer only the case of $a_1 \geq 0$

according to the information we can understand that if $a_1 \geq 0$ then it is immediately solved as $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty }(1+\frac{1}{a_n})^{a_n} =e$ since then we can look at $a_n$ as in $a_n=n$ and then the limit would be just an identity $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty }(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n}=e$

otherwise what if $a_1 <0$? we will need to show that  there exists an $N \in \Bbb N$ such that $a_N \geq 0$  we can also understand that $a_{n+1}-a_n \geq 1$ then for ever $n$ we get $a_{n+1}-a_n = (a_{n+1}-a_n)+(a_n-a_{n+1})...+(a_2 - a_1) \geq 1+1+1...+1 =n$

I do not know how to continue from here.. I usually have more ideas and stuff I tried on my posts but I really cannot figure out what to do here.

thanks for any help and tips!
edit - Thanks to all the comments I tried and cannot figure out on how to actually prove it , I do realize what the limit is worth now and why but I am struggling to prove it as I stated before

EDIT (point of the edit is to solve it organized and in a better way according to information I have and from the comments) -
Organizing information

a.
$(a_n)$ is an increasing sequence therefore we get $(1)$ $a_{n+1} > a_n$ , $(2)$ thanks to nejimban an increasing sequence of integers must tend to $\infty$ $(3)$ an increasing sequence of integers therefore $a_{n+1}-a_n \geq 1$

b. $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty }(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n}=e$

c. Need to prove that there is an $N \in \Bbb N$ such that for every $n>N$ we get $a_n>0$

Solving - posted as an answer to the question

Comment: *Hint.* An increasing sequence of integers must tend to $\infty$.

Comment: Looks like a subsequence of $(1+\frac{1}{n})^n\to e$.  Should have same limit.  Assume $a_n\to \infty$.

Comment: When computing the limit, you can always discard as finitely many terms as you wish, without affecting the limit itself. Since $(a_n)$ is (strictly) increasing, it will eventually become positive, so the linked question perfectly applies to your case.

Comment: Thank you all for the help , I now understand it better and know what the value should be $(e)$ but I am still struggling with actually proving it formally 
will update on how it goes

Comment: I still cannot solve it formally .. would appreciate a hint on how to start it or idea for it.. to prove it by definition

Comment: In your calculation it should be $a_{n+1}-a_1 \geq n$ not $a_{n+1}-a_n \geq n$. Now suppose $a_1 = -k$. Then $a_{n+k} \geq k + a_1 = 0$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1752395/960197 for example, the argument is valid for all $a_i$, including negative ones.

Comment: Just a doubt regarding the question if we assume that $a_n$ is increasing (monotonic increasing) then, it could either be bounded monotonic or unbounded, take for instance $a_{n}=\tan^{-1}(n)$, clearly this is monotonic, however $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n}=\frac{\pi}{2}$, which makes $\left(1+\frac{1}{a_N}\right)^{a_n}\not\to e$?? Do I seem to be missing something??

Comment: @SarthakSahoo It is a sequence of integers not real numbers, so successive terms grow by at least 1. I.e. $a_{n+1}-a_{n}\geq 1$.

Comment: @podiki can you please tell me why you assumed $a_1 = -k$? is it because we need to prove that even if $a_1$ is negative it will still increase to infinity? and why $a_{n+k} \geq k+a{a_1}=0 $? but specifically on why you got to $a_{n+k}$
thank you!

Comment: $a_1$ has to be an integer (the whole sequence is made up of integers). You are concerned about the case when the first element is negative, so I just gave it a name. It can be any negative integer. As for the second question, if $a_1=-7$ for example then $7$ terms later we must have a nonnegative number since the sequences goes up by at least one each term.

Comment: @podiki I think that I got it after all the great help in the comments hopefully I understood it right though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your proof can be written out a little more clearly, and with fewer steps, words and symbols. In particular, I will only use one "lemma" before moving to the main proof.

> Lemma: For each $n\in\mathbb N$, $a_n \geq a_0 + n$.
>
> Proof: Induction. For $n=0$, the proof is trivial. For general $n$, assume $a_n\geq a_0 + n$. Then, $a_{n+1} > a_n$ and $a_{n+1}$ is an integer, so $$a_{n+1}\geq a_n + 1 \geq (a_0 + n) + 1 = a_0 + (n+1)$$ which concludes the proof.

---

Main proof. Let $$b_n=\left(1+\frac1{a_{n'}}\right)^{a_{n'}}.$$

Let $\epsilon > 0$. Then, from the definition of limits and because we know that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n = e$$

we know that there exists some $M\in\mathbb N$ such that, for all $n\in \mathbb N$ such that $n\geq M$, we have $$\left|e-\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n\right|\leq\epsilon.$$

Let $M' = M - a_0$. Let $n'\in\mathbb N$ be such that $n' > M'$. Then, we have $$a_{n'} \geq a_0 + n' \geq a_0 + M' \geq a_0 + M-a_0 \geq M.$$

Therefore, we know that $a_n' \geq M$, which means that

$$|e-b_{n'}|=\left|e-\left(1+\frac1{a_{n'}}\right)^{a_{n'}}\right|\leq \epsilon.$$

Because $n'$ was arbitrary, we know that the inequality above is true for all $n'$. In other words, this proves the statement:

$$\exists M': \forall n'\in \mathbb N: n'>M'\implies |e-b_{n'}|\leq \epsilon$$

Because the choice of $\epsilon$ was arbitrary, we know that the statement above is true for all $\epsilon > 0$, and this is exactly the definition of the limit of the sequence $b_n$ being $e$.

---

In particular, the changes from your proof are:

1. There is no splitting of cases when $a_1$ is positive or negative. This splitting of cases is not needed, because in both cases, we will  need $a_n$ to eventually be not only positive, but also larger than some (usually big) number.
2. There are no subsequences in my proof, everything follows directly and cleanly from the definitions of limits.
3. There is no need for the concept of "shifted" (or "moved", as you call them) sequences.

Comment: amazing proof thank you!, does this lemma have a name?

Comment: @Adamrk Not a name I know of. Honestly, the statement in the lemma is simple enough that in most proofs, authors would simply say that the statement is "obviously" true and let the reader prove it for themselves.

Comment: thank you much appreciated , will keep this lemma in mind since I never came across it in my books happy to learn something new

Comment: @Adamrk Like I said, it might even be a bit much to call it a lemma. But yes, it is definitely worth keeping in mind that if you know a sequence increases by (at least) $s$ at each step, then it will increase by (at least) $n\cdot s$ in $n$ steps. In the case above, $s=1$, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully this is the right answer after all the amazing help in the comments and hopefully this can help someone if they struggled with this like I did.
For now I will accept my own answer as it seems logical to me but if someone finds something wrong with it please let me know

First we organize given information , conclusions and theorems we will use.

1. Given $(a_n)$ is an increasing sequence of integers therefore $a_{n+1}-a_{n}\geq1$
2. $a_{n+1} > a_n$
3. theorem : an increasing sequence which is not bounded must tend to $\infty$
4. $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty }(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n}=e$  is a known limit
5. a subsequence of a convergent sequence also converges to the original series limit
6. sequence $(b_n)$ is called a subsequence of $a_n$ if there is an increasing sequence $(n_k)$ of natural numbers that satisfies $a_{n_k}=b_k$ for every $k \in \Bbb N$

Solution:

We will first prove that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty }a_n=\infty$ for the case $a_1<0$ (if $a_1 \geq 0$ there isn't much to prove).
let $a_1 = -k \in \Bbb Z$.

therefore $a_{n+t} \geq t+a_1=0$ (as podiki said) we are checking $a_1 <0$ so we picked a first element which is an integer so let $a_1 = -t$ . if $a_1 = -t$ then since the series is increasing after $t$ terms we must have a nonnegative number since the sequence goes up by at least one each term then we get $a_{n+t} \geq 0$.
now let $N \in \Bbb N$ such that for all $n>N$ we get $a_n >a_N \geq0$ and we found such an $n$  ( $a_{n+t} \geq 0$ ) according to point **2** and point **1** we get that $a_{n+t+1} > a_{n+t}$ therefore according to point **6** this is an increasing sequence of natural numbers. then we can say that $(1+ \frac{1}{a_{n+t}})^{a_{n+t}}$ is a subsequence of $(1+ \frac{1}{n})^n$ and since according to point **4** we know that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty }(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n}=e$ then $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty }(1+ \frac{1}{a_{n+t}})^{a_{n+t}}=e$ as well, and since  $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty }(1+ \frac{1}{a_{n+t}})^{a_{n+t}}=e$ is a moved sequence of $a_n$ (sorry if it is not called "moved sequence" in english hope it is still understood) we get that $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty }(1+ \frac{1}{a_{n}})^{a_{n}}=e$